# FullCalendar 1.5 - Events not rendering until window resize in FF and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, fullcalendar

I just upgraded to the 1.5 version of FullCalendar.  I switched the JQuery and JQuery UI JS files as well as swapping the new FullCalendar JS and CSS files. After switching to the EventSources (I'm using a JSON source) I ran it on IE and it worked well.  However on FF and Chrome, the calendar shows up but you don't see any events.  I can see the request and response from my server side app so I know its returning the same data.  I add an alert in the eventAfterRender callback and it pops up immediately in IE for each event.  In FF and Chrome it doesn't.  By chance I resized a FF windows and vioala... I got the eventAfterRender alerts and all of the calendar events showed up where they are supposed to.  I tried it on Chrome too and it did the same thing.  It's as if there needs to be some other event called in FF and Chrome to make the final event rendering execute.

Comment: can you submit an official bug report?
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/

(the runnable demo is key with this problem)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
  $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  ...
  });
```

Instead of the correct:

```
  $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(function() {
    $j('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      ...
    });
  });
```

It will work in newer browsers like chrome, FF5 or IE8, but not in IE6 or IE7